# Need to find the documentations for these global variables and event names

Tags: apex, visualforce, aura, documentation

Most programming languages have a full documentation or at least a complete list of all functions and classes and a short description, I noticed a few things in aura and apex that I can't find it's documentation page.

```
// in aura / controller.js:

$A
$A.get(e.force:closeQuickAction') // where is 'e.force:closeQuickAction' defined?
$A.get('e.force:showToast') // what are these!
$A.util
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {} // the js side component class documents?

// in visualforce .page files:

$Lightning
$Lightning.use
$Lightning.createComponent
```

I'm just looking for documentations about these, and I've already tried googling these, and it just won't take me to the source!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google can't seem to find the events correctly right now, possibly because of the new URL. Try looking in the [Component Library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components), or in AuraDocs ([Production](https://login.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app) | [Sandbox](https://test.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app)) (requires Salesforce login). This will show you all the events (check under the Events section of either documentation), the latter including any custom components you develop.

For the `$Lightning` JavaScript, see [Lightning Out documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm), which is broken in to several parts, including the typical Visualforce use as well as the more unusual "hosted elsewhere" design (e.g. on a website you control).

One final note, `$A.get("e.some:event")` the "e" is the "event [value provider](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_source.htm)", like how "c" is the controller value provider, and "v" is the "value value provider." You don't really need to know what that means, just know that you need to use it when you use `$A.get` to get an event.

Comment: Omg! it's integrated with my org! that's why google can't find them! Thank you so much.

Comment: @MacA. The other one, the Component Library, is public, but doesn't seem to be properly indexed or maybe an SEO problem. I can't find anything on Google in there by default, but it does exist. But I do prefer AuraDocs because of the integrated-with-my-org feature.

Comment: so is it not possible to view the aura docs without logging in ?

Comment: @MacA. Not that AuraDocs. It's intentional, because it adds all of your custom components to the UI. But the Component Library you can view without logging in. If you prefer AuraDocs, you can always create a free Developer Edition org instead of logging in to your production org.

Comment: any chance you know where is docs for component class in controller.js ?

Comment: @MacA. I guess you're asking about [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_intro.htm)? And you can also find all the methods in AuraDocs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try referencing auradocs or [lightning component library](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components)

The way you would access them is basedomain/auradocs in lightning i.e
https://something(yourbasedomain).lightning.force.com/auradocs

Once you see the aura the aura documentation

1. Click on the reference on the top right corner
2. Now in the left side of aura docs you can check for most of the documentation.